# MonkeyTalk on Android and WebChromeClient/onJsScript conflict

Tags: javascript, android, automation, automated-tests, monkeytalk

I have configured "Monkey Talk" to work with my android app. Everything works except for the `Activity` which uses a `Webview` with a custom `WebChromeClient`, which utilizes the `onJsScript(...)` method of `WebChromeClient`. Basically, the call back never occurs and instead a dialog prompt pops up in the application. This looks similar to the problem people reported with phonegap. Does "Monkey Talk" set its own `WebChromeClient`, which could conflict with the one I use?
Anyone run into similar problems have any solutions? (The phonegap solution of installing the latest version of cordova.jar is not something helpful to me since I use neither phonegap or cordova)

If no one has fix for this problem please suggest another free test-automation tools that allows for simple test script creation (e.g. recording). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a bug in the Monkey Talk code (current version, which is 1.0.53) that causes this problem.

In MonkeyTalk's WebCrhomeClientWrapper in the override of `onJsPrompt`, `client.onJsConfirm` is called instead of `client.onJsPrompt`:

```
@Override
public boolean onJsPrompt(WebView view, String url, String message, String defaultValue,
                          final JsPromptResult result) {
    if (client.onJsConfirm(view, url, message, result)) { ...
```

Sent the info to the Monkey Talk team, hopefully they'll fix this soon.

Comment: Got a response from a Monkey Talk dev, the fix for this bug will be included in future releases.